# Is it possible to create an image from a file on a Docker host using the Docker API?

Tags: docker, docker-api

I'm trying to create a Docker image from a file on a Docker host using the Python docker API.
The client is running on a different host, so I would like to avoid downloading a file to the client and then uploading it to the Docker host.

This test:

```
import docker
d = docker.from_env()
print(d.images.client.api.import_image("/data/file.tar", "acme.com/test"))
print(d.images.client.api.import_image("file:///data/file.tar", "acme.com/test"))
```

produces the following output:

```
{"status":"Downloading from http://%2Fdata%2Ffile.tar"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"parse http://%2Fdata%2Ffile.tar: invalid URL escape \"%2F\""},"error":"parse http://%2Fdata%2Ffile.tar: invalid URL escape \"%2F\""}

{"status":"Downloading from file:///data/file.tar"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"Get file:///data/file.tar: unsupported protocol scheme \"file\""},"error":"Get file:///data/file.tar: unsupported protocol scheme \"file\""}
```

The Docker daemon 1.13 is running on a Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) VM on an ESXi 6 host. The client is a Docker Python API 2.0.2 running on a physical Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the [Docker daemon code](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/4060d6ee0b130cf74294c309dfbd3c860fd2a7f8/daemon/import.go#L62) I found out that Docker does not support local files there and always expects an HTTP response from a URL.

So I exposed the file via an HTTP server in a Docker container and sending HTTP URL.